# Ajax + change link

Tags: ajax

Как сделать так что бы менялся url страницы на registration.php ?(Заранее спасибо,не могу со сменой url вообще разобраться)

```
 $(document).ready(function()       
        {  
            $('#to_register').click(function(){  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "registration.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html',    
                    success: function(html){  
                        $(".container").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
            });     
        });
```

P.s как сделать что бы код ниже выполнялся перед запросом ajax ?

```
$("body").append('<div id="xr_splash_progress" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-image: url(images/bigrotation2.gif); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 99999;"></div>');
$("body").append('<div id="xr_splash" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.2; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999;"></div>');
```

После удачного запроса

```
$("#xr_splash_progress").remove();
$("#xr_splash").remove();
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({    
  //...    
  beforeSend:function(){ //перед отправкой },    
  success: function(data) {  },    
  error: function() { alert('fail =('); // ошибка запроса (страница не найдена, fatal server error или любая другая )  
  },    
  //...    
});
```

Обратите внимание, что после последнего элемента не ставится запятая (в php её можно ставить).

Сменить страницу можно установив свойство `window.location`

Например `window.location = 'http://google.com';`

Также `window.location = window.location;` приведет к обновлению (F5) страницы

**Добавлено 27.04.2013**

Не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите сделать.

Если хотите брать url "со стороны", то можно поместить на страницу например такую штуку:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dataProvider" value="registration.php"/>
```

и делать такой аякс:

```
$.ajax({
 url: $('#dataProvider').val(),
 //... 
});
```

Подробно о всех параметрах можно узнать из официальной [документации](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: А можно по подробнее по поводу как дописать к этой функции смену url ?Просто я в этом что то не понимаю как ...туториалы посмотрел но хз,именно как подключить к ajax load'у ?